# Correct JSON format to add a user to group using REST POST call in spHttpClient? "Input string was not in a correct format." error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am getting an '“Input string was not in a correct format.” error after submitting the following POST call:
any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

```
const addUserURL: string = newWeb + `/_api/web/sitegroups('${groupName}')/users`;     
const userOpts: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
      body: `{
        "@odata.type": "SP.User",
        "loginName": "${userKey}" // a.k.a.: "i:0#.f|membership|user.email@domain.com"
    }`
    }; 

     const addUserToGroupResponse: SPHttpClientResponse = this.props.context.spHttpClient.post(
      addUserURL,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
      userOpts);

     console.log("User has been successfully added to the security group.");
```

Comment: Modify it to `"@odata.type": "#SP.User",` and check

Comment: have tested that as well, doesn't make a difference : /

Comment: Also, change to `"loginName": "${encodeURIComponent(userKey)}"` and check ? Ensure that the `odata.type` value is as in the previous comment

Comment: edited both fields as per your recommendation, still the same error : /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `GetByName` after the `SiteGroups` endpoint.

Modify your code as :

```
const addUserURL: string = newWeb + `/_api/web/sitegroups/GetByName('${groupName}')/users`;
const userOpts: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
  body: `{
    "@odata.type": "#SP.User",
    "LoginName": "${userKey}"
}`
};
```

Comment: @lachezarStefanov - any luck with this ? Have tested the above code in my tenant and works fine.

Comment: Hello Gautam,

Thank you, adding the GetByName is a game changer here indeed. Pity too many code samples on the internet have omitted it : /

I currently struggle with adding the user to the group; I get an error "The user does not exist or is not unique." (-2130575276, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException)

Have experimented with different user properties (ex.: the DisplayText and the Description), so far no luck. Tried also adding the encodeURIComponent function, no change : /

Comment: can you try with another user for testing purposes ? I faced this issue for couple of times and after a few mins it vanished :)

Comment: Hello Gautam,

That did the trick indeed : ) entered another user and it got added successfully. Then experimented with the user, originally displaying the error and it worked with him as well.

(I was just about to use 'good old' JSOM as a workaround... thanks for keeping my code clean from deprecated mess : ) )